# What is the SHA-256 hash of a single "1" bit?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, hash, sha

The definition of SHA-256 appears to be such that the input consisting of a single "1" bit has a well-defined hash value, distinct from that of the "01" *byte* (since the padding is done based on input's length in bits).

However, due to endianness issues and the fact that no implementations that I can find support feeding in single bits, I can't quite figure out what this correct value is.

So, what is the correct hash of the **1-bit long** input consisting of the bit "1"? (not the 8-bit long byte[] { 1 } input).

Comment: You could calculate it by hand: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2#SHA-256_.28a_SHA-2_variant.29_pseudocode but it would get pretty tedious pretty fast.

Comment: sorry to add so many question marks, stupid lower limit on comments.

Comment: @Matrix the issue with that pseudocode is that some "magic" occurs where the block is split up into w[0..15] words - it is not completely clear if w[0] should be 0x00000003 or 0xC0000000 (or, indeed, whether it should be w[15] containing one of those values).

Comment: @Eric no, this is hobby stuff. Why, does it make a difference?

Comment: since is hobby stuff you may be interested in RC4, which is a stream cipher. It's kind of strange what you are trying to achieve with SHA2

Comment: and also will be strange in RC4

Comment: @Eric what is so strange about having a number of bits that is not a multiple of 8?

Comment: @rom then maybe try this: http://www.webtoolkit.info/javascript-sha256.html It looks like it's designed to take a string, but maybe you could modify it to take a sequence of bits, or at least read it and get a better understanding of the algorithm. (For extra credit, go back to the part of the Wikipedia pseudocode that was unclear, and edit it to make it clearer!)

Comment: let me compute the time for bruteforcing 1 bit

Comment: @Eric you seem to think that there is never a reason to compute the hash of a short input. I can give you one: verifying the correctness of an implementation. [The hash of the 0 bit input](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Examples_of_SHA_digests#SHA-256_hashes) can be used as one of the test cases. The two 1 bit strings would also be handy. If you don't want to answer this question then by all means don't, but I don't understand why you seem to imply this question is stupid.

Comment: So you want to use 256bits to make sure 1 bit was sent correctly. How will you make sure the hash is correct with a 2**20?

Comment: @Eric Fortis: I see nothing outlandish about the question. The hash functions themselves are *defined* in terms of arbitrarily long bit strings, so why shouldn't someone perhaps be interested in actually computing on such arbitrary bit strings. And for testing, clearly you want to test the trivial cases such a a single bit, or two bits.

Comment: Testing the implementation is a good reason, My apologies to ron

Answer (score 11, accepted):

OK, according to my own implementation:

**1-bit string "1"**:

```
B9DEBF7D 52F36E64 68A54817 C1FA0711 66C3A63D 384850E1 575B42F7 02DC5AA1
```

**1-bit string "0"**:

```
BD4F9E98 BEB68C6E AD3243B1 B4C7FED7 5FA4FEAA B1F84795 CBD8A986 76A2A375
```

I have tested this implementation on several standard multiples-of-8-bits inputs, including the 0-bit string, and the results were correct.

(of course the point of this question was to validate the above outputs in the first place, so use with care...)

Comment: I confirm these values. My own implementation of SHA-2 is from sphlib ( http://www.saphir2.com/sphlib/ ). The C code handles inputs with lengths not multiple of 8.

Comment: Also confirmed by Perl's implementation, which accepts strings in binary encoding.

Comment: Also confirmed using https://pypi.org/project/sha256bit/ (well, the 1-bit "0" is definitely right as it match the test vector given by NIST in https://csrc.nist.gov/CSRC/media/Projects/Cryptographic-Algorithm-Validation-Program/documents/shs/shabittestvectors.zip see SHA256ShortMsg.rsp)

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if I understand your question correctly.

SHA-256 operates with block sizes of 64 bytes (=512bits). This means smaller inputs must be padded first. The result of the padding looks like this:

```
For Bit 1:    1100000000000...00000000001
For Bits 01:  0110000000000...00000000010
```

As this results are distinct, the results of the following compression functions will be too. And therefore the hash values are. The standard document explains the padding quite descriptive: http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/fips/fips180-2/fips180-2.pdf

Comment: not only SHA-256, I can't think of any algorithm that doesn't pad or repeat small inputs.

Comment: The block size for SHA256 is 512 bits not 256 bits. See RFC: 4634 "US Secure Hash Algorithms (SHA and HMAC-SHA)", http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4634.txt

Comment: @BabuSrinivasan Confirmed. `hashlib.sha256().block_size` returns `64`.

Answer (score 2):

There is C code available in [section 8](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4634#section-8) of [RFC 4634](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4634) to compute the hash of data that is not necessarily a multiple of 8 bits. See the methods whose names are `SHA*FinalBits(...)`.