# Python: get sha256() hash digest of a single bit in Python

Tags: python, hash, sha256

Or, in general, any arbitrary number or bits that is not a multiple of 8.

According to [hashlib.py](https://docs.python.org/2/library/hashlib.html) there is one constructor method named for SHA256. Then I use sha256() to create a SHA256 hash object. I can now feed this object with arbitrary strings using the update() method, and at any point I can ask it for the digest of the concatenation of the strings fed to it so far using the digest() or hexdigest() methods.

Well. I would like to feed 1 bit to SHA256 in line with this link ["What is the SHA-256 hash of a single '1' bit?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4422970/what-is-the-sha-256-hash-of-a-single-1-bit)

In Python 2.7, of course.

So, what is the procedure to hash 1-bit long input consisting of the bit "1"? (not the 8-bit long byte[] { 1 } input)?

Comment: Yes, but the padding is done based on the input's length in bits. There are examples in other languages, there is C code available in [section 8][1] of [RFC 4634][2] to compute the hash of data that is not necessarily a multiple of 8 bits. See the methods whose names are `SHA*FinalBits(...)`.


  [1]: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4634#section-8
  [2]: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4634

Comment: yes, BUT THERE IS NO 1-BIT TYPE IN PYTHON

Comment: Of course there is, it is called boolean.

Comment: @allo: care to demonstrate?

Comment: @DIUUSIULIUS This sounds like a beginning of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Are you trying to achieve something specific, or is it just curiosity? Most real world protocols either pad the number, or have a specific encoding for the arbitrary length integers and hash that instead (like BER).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither the `hashlib` API nor the underlying C module support anything but "buffers of bytes".

Since the SHA standard prescribes adding something to *any* message, regardless of length, you cannot even "pre-pad" your input in python to get around that restriction.

To demonstrate (taken from https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4634#section-4.1):

```
>>> sha256('abcde').hexdigest()
'36bbe50ed96841d10443bcb670d6554f0a34b761be67ec9c4a8ad2c0c44ca42c'

>>> sha256('abcde\x80' + 57*'\x00' + '\x28').hexdigest()
'45cb103e6385e1330c892d1566d4d82f0c1c256947e54206704973c6c2adf4f6'
```

Although calculating the hash of a message with a length that is not a multiple of 8 might technically be allowed, I would very much doubt that there are real world use cases for this (that require the use of only the python standard lib, no less).

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://pypi.org/project/sha256bit/

Same interface as hashlib except that the `update` function has an optional argument `bitlen` to support bit granularity.

```
>>> from sha256bit import Sha256bit
>>> h=Sha256bit()
>>> h.update(b'\x00',bitlen=1)
>>> h.hexdigest()
'bd4f9e98beb68c6ead3243b1b4c7fed75fa4feaab1f84795cbd8a98676a2a375'
```